# Alternative to using same foreign key in almost every table

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I am working with a database where "almost" every table in the database has the same field and same value.  For example, almost all tables have a field called GroupId and there is only one group id in the database now.

Benefits

- All data is related to that field and can be identified by said field
- When a new group is created data will be properly identified for the group

Disadvantages

- All tables have the this field
- All stored procedures need to have this field as a parameter
- All queries have to filtered by this field

Is this a big deal?  Is there an alternative to this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the problem you're trying to solve? Without some of the domain-specific knowledge, this seems like discussion the difference between six and half-a-dozen.

Comment: I believe this is a situation where the domain-specific information is not necessary.  This can be applied across many domains.  If it helps you can think of the groupid as a customerid.  All data that is related to the customer (as opposed to the group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to identify data by more than one group in the future, having foreign keys is a good practice. However, that deosn't mean all tables need to have this field, only the ones directly related to the group. For instance a lookuptable with state values may not need it, but the customers table might. Adding it to all tables willy-nilly can lead to bad things when you try to delete a record and have to check 579 tables (only 25 of which are pertinent).  All this depends greatly on what the meaning of the groups is. Most of our tables have a relationship to the client table, because they contain data related to specific clients and because we don't want various clients to have the ability to see data for other clients. Tables which do not contain that kind of data do not.

Yes most queries may need the field and many stored procs will want to have it as an input variable, but if you truly need to filter on this information, then that is as it should be.

If however there is only one group and will never be more than one group, it is a waste of time, effort and space.

Comment: Why would I want to? This is how relational tables are supposed to work.